# Get list of includes in a parsed document

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm parsing an **asciidoc** document using [asciidoctor.js](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.js) library. The document has doctype of `book`. I need to get list of all the included documents (asciidoc) in this `book` doc.

Although, the library gives API for accessing document's includes but it does not return any useful/meaningful data. Here's what I tried:

```js
const doc = asciidoctor().loadFile('/path/to/asciidoc/book')
if (doc.getDoctype() === 'book') {
    console.log(doc.getReferences().includes)
}
```

This logs following output:

```js
klass {
  '$$smap': {},
  '$$map': [Object: null prototype] {},
  '$$keys': []
}
```

I double checked and the book document which is being parsed already has some `include`s in it.

How do you access list of included documents with **asciidoctor.js** ?